# HTML Double Action: How do i send a form and delete a column at the same time?

Tags: php, html, button

is it possible in html to have a button that submits the data and at the same time lets you delete some data? i have here:

```
 ...some form inputs here...

 <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/report/deleteRequest/<?php echo $id; ?>" type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="return confirm('are you sure to reject this request?')">Reject</a>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Accept</button>
  <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/report/" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Back</a>
```

i want my accept button to delete the request after accepting it. so basically, i need to have those to work on sync. is that possible? if not, i know there is another way.

Comment: In your PHP script that processes the form, you can do pretty much whatever you like

Comment: i want my  Accept button to Reject a request. how do i do that?

Comment: @henrywright but you shouldn't do illegal things.

Comment: hey guys, some help here? i just want to do it like this: <button type="submit" href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/report/deleteRequest/<?php echo $id; ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Accept</button> but how do i exactly do that?

Answer (score 0):

Submitting a form doesn't "accept" or "delete" anything - it simply passes data to the script defined in the forms action. You need to have a function in the script that you pass the data to that does what you want, and trigger it with the data you pass. 
So if you are POSTing to deleteRequest.php (or.asp or whatever) it would have

```
If ($_POST ['addAndDelete'] == 'true')
{
//add stuff
//delete stuff
//launch a rocket
}
```